# Как послать запрос с доменом внутри url?

Tags: node.js, http, взлом

Есть обычный сервер на nodejs:

```
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 8888;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log(req.url);
  console.log(req.method);
  console.log(req.connection.remoteAddress);
  console.log('===');

  // Some server implementation
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
  console.log('===');
});
```

Открыл доступ к нему на порту `8888` и со временем получил пару необычных логов:

```
http://www.baidu.com/favicon.ico
GET
43.241.222.224
```

```
http://www.baidu.com/cache/global/img/gs.gif
GET
93.174.93.136
```

Понятно, что так что-то прощупывают, но возник другой вопрос: какие бы я запросы не посылал, `req.url` всегда начинается со слеша, отделяющего путь от домена:

```
/cache/global/img/gs.gif
```

Попытался даже кинуть символ с кодом 8, но такой запрос до обработчика вообще не дошёл.

**Так как же сформировать и послать такой запрос, что nodejs распарсит его с получением `url` вместе с доменом?** Валиден ли такой запрос вообще?

Comment: Это похоже на обычный запрос к HTTP-proxy. Там как раз указывается полный адрес. Попробуйте настроить браузер, указав ему свой сервер как прокси, и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, я пробовал через фиддлер запрос сформировать - что-то не вышло... Браузер - хм...

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, да, действительно так получается. А как бы запрос в сыром виде увидеть?

Comment: ну, залогить реквест полностью, если на стороне сервера (с NodeJS практически не знаком, извините), а в браузере и так можно посмотреть, что он шлет. Ну а ситуация, скорее всего, такова, что какой-то бот как-то узнал про новый хост и проверил, не работает ли на нем прокси по стандартным портам.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, не получается по тому, что показывает браузер, воспроизвести полностью структуру запроса.

Comment: если вы хотите искусственно повторить такой запрос из скрипта, то вроде бы там для прокси/обычный вся разница именно в адресе - абсолютный/относительный. Но чтобы отправить абсолютный, надо создавать голый socket, в который можно писать, что угодно (так в C), а какие-то надстройки над socket могут ваш адрес самовольно преобразовать в относительный.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov, т. е. через тот же fiddler такой запрос не воспроизвести?

Comment: Погуглил, fiddler, если все правильно понял, это сам по себе прокси, а тут вы свой сервер пытаетесь использовать как прокси. Вроде, это другое.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57867/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-alexander-zonov).